# OpenCL Android Matrix Multiplication Out of memory (mmap fail errno 12)

Tags: android, matrix, opencl, mmap, multiplication

I am new to Android, JNI, and OpenCL. I am working on passing java matrices to native, performing OpenCL matrix multiplication, and passing result array back to java (in android with Adreno 330.)

I have built my code largely off of the adreno sdk sample and it compiles but it appears that I'm running out of memory creating my device buffers.

```
// First matrix (device)
cl_mem matrixA;
// Second Matrix (device)
cl_mem matrixB;
// Matrix product result (device)
cl_mem matrixProduct;

// Cast parameters
NumRowsA = (size_t)NumRowsA;  // 2
NumColsARowsB = (size_t)NumColsARowsB; // 2
NumColsB = (size_t)NumColsB; // 2
size_t NumFloatsA = NumRowsA * NumColsARowsB;
size_t NumFloatsB = NumColsB * NumColsARowsB;


// Create device buffers
matrixA = clCreateBuffer( openCLObjects.context,
        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
        NumFloatsA * sizeof(cl_float),
        NULL,
        &err );

// ERROR OCCURS BELOW
// mmap fail (pid 21957, tid 21957, size 2155245568, flags 0x1, errno 12 (Out of Memory)

matrixB = clCreateBuffer( openCLObjects.context,
        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
        NumFloatsB * sizeof(cl_float),
        NULL,
        &err );
```

I am only passing 2x2 matrices right now. When I debug, NumFloatsB * sizeof(cl_float) = 16. I do not allocate any memory on the GPU prior to this.

OPENCL ERROR CODE: CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY

Comment: Looks like a driver error. Can you provide Device + Android Version?

Comment: HTC One M8
Android 5.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was short one parameter (NumColsB) in my mainactivity.java.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a driver issue, you could try the following to work around that:

1) Back the clBuffer with memory allocated on the host:

```
void *mem_ptr = malloc(NumFloatsA * sizeof(cl_float));
matrixA = clCreateBuffer( openCLObjects.context,
        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
        NumFloatsA * sizeof(cl_float),
        mem_ptr,
        &err );
```

(*NOTE: remember to free mem_ptr after releasing the clBuffer*)

2) Force the driver allocating memory on the host:

```
matrixA = clCreateBuffer( openCLObjects.context,
        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
        NumFloatsA * sizeof(cl_float),
        NULL,
        &err );
```

Comment: what kind of error you get? still out of memory? does the malloc returns a valid pointer or NULL?

Comment: I am getting the same error as before. There was no change, out of memory. Malloc appears to return a valid pointer.